# Minecraft - Custom Dimensions for Servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Would it be possible to create custom dimensions on servers by using plugins and custom-generated separate worlds? Has this been done already?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean different *worlds*? Transporting between different worlds is possible and is in fact widely used by most modded servers.

The Spigot plugin [Multiverse](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/multiverse-core.390/) provides such functionality. It allows users to generate new worlds and travel between them. Visit the link above which leads you to the plugin page for more detailed information about Multiverse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,as you said, with plugins or mods. Here are some you may need depending on what do you use as server-api: [Bukkit](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/multiworld-v-2-0) or [Sponge](https://forums.spongepowered.org/t/project-worlds-world-manager/10170) are for worlds(like hobbys); or a plugin for [Bukkit](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/magicworlds)(needs Magic plugin) for dimensions
I suggest anyway googling before posting or at least show what you came up with